# iPhone: get video informations

Tags: iphone, ios

Say I have a video which iPhone can play, I want to get these informations:

```
codec

format

demuxer

duration

h264 profile

h264 level

FPS

width in pixel

height in pixel

audio format

audio bitrate

audio channel count
```

I believe there is some class or framework for this in iOS, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `AVFoundation`. Look at the docs for `AVAsset`.

Comment: any hint? I read the doc and find those metadata methods, but all of them returns empty array.

Comment: You should be able to loop through the `commonMetadata` array to view the `AVMetadataItem`s, if available.

Comment: The array commonMetadata returned is an empty array, my asset is OK, I can play it.

Comment: Interesting. It does note that it will only display metadata it contains. Where is this file from, and are you sure it contains metadata?

Comment: AVAsset can get meta data of these types: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationMetadataKeyReference/Reference/reference.html , but not enough for my need. I see VLC player can get all these data I need, but I don't know how it does it.